# Openerp create 2 bar in graph view

Tags: odoo

How to make 2 group bar like this image in openerp graph ?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVyDf.png)

My xml is :

```
<field name='productfunction' group="True"/>
<field name='average_gross_margin_fnc'/>
```

But it show **only** average_gross_margin_fnc.

Please answer.
Thank you

Comment: Could you please add the code of your whole record?
And maybe a screenshot of how it looks in odoo right now.

Comment: <graph string="Margin Analysis By Function" type="bar">
 <field name='productfunction' type='row'/>
 <field name='average_net_margin_fnc'/>
 <field name='average_gross_margin_fnc'/>
</graph>

I will group it by Average Net Margin and Average Gross Margin,
How can I do that ?
Thankyou

Comment: The graph image is here : https://snag.gy/Gh9n8P.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is a double grouping. In the screenshot you have posted you have grouped by Sales Team and Date Order, try grouping your records using your fields. Also click on the Grouped element on the top left of your chart instead of Stacked

Comment: <graph string="Margin Analysis By Function" type="bar">
 <field name='productfunction' type='row'/>
 <field name='average_net_margin_fnc'/>
 <field name='average_gross_margin_fnc'/>
</graph>

I will group it by Average Net Margin and Average Gross Margin,
If I add group="True" in these field, It show notice that no y-axis..

Please help, thank you